# How Can I or Should I Fine Tune Node.js/Socket.io Chat App So It Doesn't Drag Down My Entire Website/Server?

Tags: php, node.js, express, socket.io, mysql2

I built a chatroom w/ NodeJs using, socket.io, mysql2 & express packages. It's extremely dynamic including public chats, private messaging, and other unique features to make it lively, ie real time updates, notifications, etc.

Originally built and tested on a dummy domain and was working perfectly fine. And then I moved it over to my main website domain when finished. Now that it is, I'm experiencing horrible site load speeds. However, both domains (the test domain site and main live site were on the same server).

The server; 2x Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2697 v4, 64GB RAM, 4x 480GB SSD, HW RAID storage, Network port 1 Gbps, 2 ipv4 addresses, bandwidth 50 TB, Centos 7, cpanel included and have.
About 1000 users actively use the website/chat.
The chatroom is negatively impacting the rest of the site and slowing it all down. Initial server response is roughly 14 seconds, but in worst case scenarios has been as long as 30+ seconds. Whereas on the test domain it was only literally 1 second. It goes without saying I should expect as good a load times as on the original test domain as a live one with real users, but this bad? I digress.

I ran speed tests. The results of those tests kept reporting back to me the initial load time was too long and literally said nothing in specific to point me to what the problem was so I assumed it was MYSQL, php, among other things. I optimized it all to the best of my ability. But after the site kept dragging, I still kept getting the same results. I finally removed things from the site one by one and when I removed the chat, the site loaded perfectly fine. It was odd, because none of the speed tests pointed to the chat or node in particular being the reasoning.

So then I optimized Node in the following ways.
-I tried adding pooling to the sql connection, trying different numbers, from 5-500,
-I tried adding a PoolManager to the database connection.
-I removed the ability for all visitors to stay connected to our node server. They're socket connection would be terminated if they didn't mean certain cretia.
-I added some parallelize to the code. To run some functions that called the database.
-I made sure to add keys and avoided long sql queries, used LIMIT, and avoided *

Put it back on the site, still the same horrible load times.

After some research I am hopeful (but still only guessing) that the following may be cause for concern;

-The server is defaulting to polling. So maybe that might be causing an issue.
Since I assume everytime it polls it has to connect and disconnect from the database server which will cause a pretty big delay since I read that a lot of issue are there.
-I tried to fixing the polling but have not been able to get it to work. I tried forcing transport:

> ['websocket']

, with all different types of settings, CORS, secure, and etc.

I read into possibly using Redis for caching and I think it can be implemented in some areas for sure. But with how lively the chat is. Cache might be limited in how often it can be used.

If there are any problems with my own code I might guess it is here.

```
//server
const f = require('./functions.js');
const db = require('./db.js');
const cookie = require('cookie');
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");


const port = 3000;
const appBaseUrl = "/node";
const socketBaseUrl = "/node/socket";

global.last_message_time = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');


// Create the server and socket
const expressApp = express();
const nodeServer = http.createServer(expressApp);
const socketIo = new Server(nodeServer, {
    path: socketBaseUrl,
});


//client 
const chat = io.connect("domain.com", {path: "/node/socket"});
```

But at the end of the day I am still at a loss and so I look to you and throw myself at the mercy of StackOverflow. Opinions, feedback and ideas as to why the chat is not playing nicely with my website would be more appreciated than you know. Thank you in advance and I look forward to hearing from you.

------------------------------Update

@Gaëtan Boyals - the additional code you asked for concerning where messages are handled, below.

```
let chats = []
            await db.getMessages(data.id, user.user_id, user.isAdmin, 'user')
            .then(response=>{
                chats = response.reverse();
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            })

            let chats_html = [];
            for(let chat of chats){
                chat.message_type = chat.type;
                chat.images       = [];
                chat.small        = [];
                if(chat.type=='photos'){
                    let encoded = JSON.parse(chat.message);
                    for(let small of encoded){
                        let j = f.createToken(small);
                        chat.small.push(j+ "?height=150");
                        chat.images.push(j)
;
                    }
                }
                //might cause issues later so see what's up here.
                
                chat.emojis       = await db.getEmojiReactions(1, chat.id);
                chat.avatar       = f.createToken(chat.avatar);
                chats_html.push(f.createMessage(chat, user.user_id, user.user_type)); 
            }
            let chat_info = await db.getPrivateRoom(data.id, user.user_id);
            socket.join(chat_info);
            user.current_room = data.id;
            user.current_type = 'user';
            user.room = chat_info;

            let send = {chats:chats_html};
            socketIo.to(socket.id).emit('get-chat', send);

            let best_badge = await db.bestBadge(data.id);
            let user_1     = await db.getUserFromId(data.id);
            user_1.badge   = best_badge ? best_badge.badge_id:false;
            user_1.avatar  = f.createToken(user_1.avatar);
            
            let group_user_html = [];
            group_user_html.push(f.rightSideUsers(user_1));
            group_user_html.push(f.rightSideUsers(user));
            socketIo.to(socket.id).emit('right-users', group_user_html);

if(user.current_room != 0){
            let isMuted = false;
            if(data.type=='group'){
                isMuted = await db.isMuted(user.user_id, data.id);
            }
            if(!isMuted){
                data.user_id = user.user_id;
                data.to      = data.id;
                if(data.message_type == 'photos'){
                    data.message = JSON.stringify(data.message);
                }
                
                if(user.user_id==0){
                    data.guest = user.username;
                }
                db.newMessage(data)
                .then((response)=>{
                    if(response){
                        
                        if(data.type=='group'){
                            db.setChatMeta(response, 'group', data.id,user.user_id);
                        }else{
                            db.setChatMeta(response, 'user', data.id,user.room);
                        }
                        

                        data.id      = response;
                        data.chat_id = response;
                        let html     = f.createMessage(data, user.user_id, user.user_type);
                         
                        let new_data = f.createRightData(data);
                        new_data.message = new_data.message.replace('<br />', '');
                        let uni = user.room;
                        let send = {html:html, id:uni,type:data.type}
                        if(data.message_type == 'video'){
                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                socketIo.in(user.room).emit("new-message",send);
                                socketIo.emit('refresh');

                            }, 5000)
                            
                        }else{
                            console.log(user.room);
                            socketIo.in(user.room).emit("new-message",send);
                            socketIo.emit('refresh');

                        }
                        
                    }
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }else{
                socketIo.to(socket.id).emit('muted')
            }
        }
```

GET and SET messages.

Comment: Did you do load tests on your dummy site where it runs fine, to exclude the fact that it's the 1000 active users that are causing this? Can you show a bit more code as well (where you effectively handle messages etc)? That is a very generic server you posted and I fail to see how such a little NodeJS server would lag up to TimeOut errors.

Comment: Yes. To an extent. There are different aspects to the chat as mentioned, like the main chat room(s) and private messaging, separately, I have taken apart different aspects of the app  piece by piece and limited users on it, and that does not seem in of itself to be the issue. Users or no users actively using it, just it simply running on the website causes the lag. I will definitely edit my original post and put up some more code for you.

Comment: Updated @GaëtanBoyals

Comment: Okay, did not see the update, thank you for the added code, but in the meantime I thought about your problem again and again and I highly doubt it has anything to do with the code you presented. Can you tell us a bit more about the setup higher up? What other service (since you're mentionning PHP) are you running? Do you have a reverse proxy routing all the setup? Seems to me that you try to route single requests to multiple services, causing a confusion on what service should handle a specific request. Do you have the possibility to setup a sub-domain?

Comment: I have a php server running a very complex php script. Essentially this chat goes to a social media type site, with video streaming but even then, without the chat it still loads extremely quickly. Very dynamic. I use passenger core through cpanel to run the server.

However, reverse proxy, single routes, these are new to me so I would say 'no' I do not. I am self taught for the most part and so I am at a loss there. But yes, I could could setup a sub domain? Just not sure to which extent I should concerning this app in particular.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, is this all hosted on a single server? Is the Node.js app hosting the site and websocket? I can determine your issue fairly quickly I run many to many broadcasting sites and handle crowds no problems. :)

Comment: Also, how many concurrent users do you have; it should be more telling of if it's hardware limitations and you just need to scale up now.

Comment: I will write a (kind of) elaborate answer about what I **think** it is after I finish diner. It is not hardware limitations though, that is for sure. Also, the current max active user is approx. 1000, it is clearly stated in the OP question.

Comment: Yeah single server. Nodejs is only for the chat, php,apache, and mysql do the rest of the site. We have roughly 1k member of the website that have access to the chat at any given time, however, concurrently, or actively using, maybe 300 users online at a single time. I did talk to my host about upscaling, and they talked me out of it because I just got done purchasing a larger server from them and they assured me it should be handling my traffic fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your 12-core server is not very large at all, at least when combining multiple applications. Your mileage may vary and greatly in some cases if the database was using all 12-cores and the Node.js app is using 1 core but gets bumped a lot the Node.js app suffers.

Now I don't know how large your site is how many users hit the site, but 12-cores of power is a lot of power...

1 core of power my HTTP server can handle a million request an hour with "many timeouts" this though would be hitting a single core database on a different server.
So if we do the math here, that's quite a lot of requests we got there and you can benchmark to see yourself.

---

The issue for the OP is that they are not properly utilizing Node.JS. They are running a single instance of their app that uses a single core and HTTPS is shared with the websockets severely limiting the service to a single core both HTTPS/WSS.

The solution is becoming stateless and turning that single core Node.JS app into a multi-core app. This requires a some knowledge on vertically scaling and horizontally scaling an app. So with those numbers the OP posted in response a single core is straight kicking.

Good luck, this I'd blame on NodeJS for now due to the 12-cores and you not hosting the media servers. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah single server. Nodejs is only for the chat, php,apache, and mysql do the rest of the site. We have roughly 1k member of the website that have access to the chat at any given time, however, concurrently, or actively using, maybe 300 users online at a single time. I did talk to my host about upscaling, and they talked me out of it because I just got done purchasing a larger server from them and they assured me it should be handling my traffic fine.

Comment: That's your problem then...

Comment: Get MySQL off the same server as the application, and for your Node.JS it runs single core default unless you cluster run workers and sticky your sessions/etc.

Comment: So imagine my first line exactly, MySQL is tuned to use all cores... It's over-riding the event-loop of your Node.JS app that just wants a single core but with other apps not caring it could be 100% across all croes and Node.JS is lagging at 20% cause MySQL took its core at a full 80%

Comment: Your best practice here is to get MySQL on its own server, Chat (websocket) on its own server, HTTPS on its own server and if you handle sessions, put that on its own server and you should be fine. Sticky session web-sockets and vertically scale those to 2-4 cores on a new server and you be GG

Comment: Any questions do ask, but your problem is quite clear it's a fight over CPU. If you have MySQL logs that suggest longest latencies on queries post that and we can determine if you need to rebuild your tables/relations or chill out on some features or determine better scaling! Also ditch Socket.IO it's major over-head for an app that doesn't require it. You can use raw web sockets and program them to be faster.

Comment: I should stress again how new I am to a lot of this, and have been self taught largely up to this point. So at the risk of sounding dumb, do you literally mean purchasing a new/separate server to run this from? 

And what do you mean exactly by logging MySQL queries? Clustering workers I could also definitely use some clarification on as well.  But by sticky sessions, is that just essentially PHP sessions?

Comment: We should maybe have a conversation about this, to make it easier. But yes, setting up new servers but of a smaller/cheaper size to not congest bandwidth and isolate the processes nicely (this will come handy when scale comes into play). As for logging MySQL, you'll have a list of queries recently used and the cost/latency of them to determine which queries are really hurting mysql vs others.

Comment: I would definitely be open to a conversation if you wouldn't mind. I'd hate to impose but I greatly appreciate your time and knowledge on this.

Comment: Clustering/Workers is the idea of introducing another application so you'd have HTTP-1 and HTTP-2 server running under a single server but both using a core each. (I got house renovations so not programming currently haha)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240971/discussion-between-bgphijack-and-rustygates).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell going through that I believe somehow your server is filling to create web socket connections and use polling as a fallback. Which basically means a huge overhead. Can you perhaps separate the chat functionality to a separate node application and possibly containerize it?. Make the initial site load and then load the chat feature until you figure out what exactly is the root cause for this.

Answer (score 0):

The user @S1ckhead already partly said what I'm about to explain, but I'll try to go more into details.

As I said in the comments, keep in mind that it's what I **think** is happening, but then again, @S1ckhead seems to have roughly the same idea as me so you might want to read on, even if it won't provide a full-baked solution.

#### This is *not* a hardware-related problem

Of course, we can brag about our personal set-ups and since we're at it, if I can run a self-hosted, bare-metal K8s cluster with three 2006 Dell PCs handling a Redis instance, a MongoDB instance and about 30 micro-services, I think the OP can run a PHP site, a NodeJS service and a MySQL instance with the specs he gave in his question **just fine**. Hell, when I was an employee at a certain company I could even run an ElasticSearch with maybe 1/3 of the budget his whole specs amount to.

He mentioned contacting his host about the issue and asked them if he should upscale, they said no and I think they are the most qualified people to say so.

Also, imagine running only an instance of anything (Php, MySQL, you name it) per server... We're not all Bill Gates, and there's no need for us to be.

#### Reverse-proxy? Routing?

I will assume you have basic or intermediate level when it comes to Sys Admin / Networking, since you know how to set-up domains and link it to your server.

A reverse proxy is basically a software that routes the client request to specific applications. For example, let's say you have 3 domains (domainA.com, domainB.com, domainC.com), all pointing to the same IP address (so basically, the same machine). How does the server know that domainA should hit the PHP site, and domainB should hit a NodeJS service? That's where the reverse proxy comes in handy. That is very roughly explained, but you can find more explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and if you are like me and prefer graphic representations, here is one:

[image: reverse proxy graphic representation]

Now I'm not going to lie, I am not familiar **at all** with cPanel, PHP and such, I usually go the no-admin-tools route and host NodeJS-based apps, but you can surely set-up a reverse proxy with your set-up.

#### What is the real problem

Again, mentioning @S1ckhead, Socket.IO is probably using [long-polling](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#how-does-that-work) as a default, but why?

Since in your code, you make socketIO listen on your main domain: `const chat = io.connect("domain.com", {path: "/node/socket"});`, the WebSocket requests will probably go to your PHP app. But your PHP app is probably not configured to handle WebSockets requests, only HTTP ones, so it defaults to long-polling. You can read more [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/), but basically, stating this site:

> The server holds the request open until new data is available. Once available, the server responds and sends the new information.

So since it holds the request until something new happens, it could explain why you experience this extremely laggy feeling.

#### What should you do?

Well, you could go two routes, the first one and the easiest would be to loan a new server, buy another domain or subdomain, link the two together, host your NodeJS app here and link your main site to this new domain/subdomain.

The other, greatly reducing costs, would be to setup a reverse proxy as previously mentioned. It could prove to be a difficult challenge (I did it with no previous experience myself, but I also had no work obligations/pressure to do it) however. It is up to you and your constraints/requirements to chose which one you want to follow.

Of course, other problems will arise when your pool of user grow larger, and the question of scaling will make sense, but that's not the concern right now.

#### A final note on Socket.IO

Keep in mind that Socket.IO is a wrapper around the [Web Socket protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), and that it will only work with its client/server counterpart (meaning you can't wire up your own WebSockets client implementation with a Socket.IO server and vice-versa). That probably means you will have to write your own WebSockets implementation since I can't seem to find an up-to-date implementation of Socket.IO in PHP. (and I don't even know if that's possible at all, again, I'm not a PHP expert)

Comment: Amazing and wonderful response, thank you. Very informative and gives me a lot to think about and start trying. (I also appreciate the graphic, haha). I feel it is worth mentioning though, I have VERY little sysadmin knowledge. Most of what I've done up to this point has been building and learning as I went along. So this would be the first time I would be approaching most of these types of matters.
The code with me initializing the socket connections has been tinkered with a lot. As I stated. I played around with CORS, Secure and Transport options and none of that has worked out for me.

Comment: Oops, I got caught up in my own explanation and forgot a link! (in the reverse proxy part, right before the image).
I can understand your feeling, after all, network admin and sys admin are jobs of their own, so it's totally normal to be overflowed with knowledge. (I've been there too, I only have a software engineer degree and self-taught most of my knowledge on networking/sys admin, like you, and I've only scratched the surface).
I'm sure you'll get there, and I'm glad my answer could at least help you to find something to tinker with!